# How to formulate a JSONP request

Tags: gwt, jsonp

I am in the process of learning GWT, I am currently facing a problem with making an RPC call to a specific server using JSONP.

The server I want to communicate with offers JSON-RPC service requiring the request to have a header of `{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`, and a body of a regular JSON data, for example: `{"params": ["HelloServer"], "method": "server.greeting", "id": 10}`.

I wonder if it possible to make a JSONP request to this server, because I suppose JSONP is the *only* workaround to the SameOriginPolicy restriction of GWT.

---

**edit**: as [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) explained, I guess I have to stick to JSON as the server does not provide JSONP service. The suggested SOP workaround is perfect, it is also suggested [here](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5&s=google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5&t=GettingStartedJSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if it possible to make a JSONP request to this server

Not if the server doesn't support it. Here's how the server response need to be modified in order to support JSONP:

```
someCallback({"params": ["HelloServer"], "method": "server.greeting", "id": 10})
```

where `someCallback` is the name of a function which could be specified by the client. If you don't have control over the server and it doesn't support JSONP your only chance is to write a server side script on your domain which will act as a bridge. Then you will send the AJAX request to this script which will delegate it to the remote domain.

Comment: I am using GWT, actually I tried to communiate with the server using XML-RPC, but I got the SOP problem! I wonder how to implement your solution in GWT, thank you so much for the information